User management using Entra for backend API
I am trying to design a user management workflow. I tried to lookup articles in microsoft learning and could not find a solution. I want to create users in Entra using a SPA. After that, user will log into the SPA. Once authenticated by Entra, I would want to fetch the user role, put it into a JWT and call a backend API on Springboot. In the backend API, I will use JWT to determine, the authorisation level of the user and invoke certain endpoint.
Can someone help me undertsand if this is possible and if so, please point me in the direction of related articles?

I somewhat recently did something similar. I'm sharing the links I saved here in hopes that it'll help you.
spring boot with azure ad/entra id
Application and resource server in one application
Injecting secrets in a spring app in azure k8s
